# Null Php Variable when inserting data into mysql db

Tags: php, database, web, mysqli, service

So i'm working on an Android project using web services.
I've got some problems like while inserting some data in my db, my php doesn't recognize the variable or something like that and it does insert value "0" for numbers and a blank space for Strings after testing with postman or even the app itself.

Here's my PHP file content :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("...","...","...","...");

    $card_number = $_POST["card_number"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO card (card_number,card_solde,date_exp) VALUES ('$card_number',0,2024)";

    mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  
    echo json_encode($response);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here's an image for the table schema and the result of the insertion.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K18X9.jpg

Thank youuu :))

Comment: what is your table schema? please show the tables column attributes.

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump` of `$_POST` please?

Comment: what is the actual value of `$card_number` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie i've typed a random 16 digits number using postman params

Comment: Maybe show a snip of what Postman shows you.

Comment: @ChinLeung here's the result for var_dump($card_number) => string(11) "card_number" , i dunno why it says string type ..

Comment: What if you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @CodeGodie here's the postman pic https://imgur.com/mrfj8Hg

Comment: @ChinLeung var_dump($_POST) => array(0) { }

Comment: See my answer, you need to put your params in the BODY not the URL

Comment: @WalidBraham You're not receiving the post properly... Your $_POST is empty. How are you sending the data to your PHP file?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help it worked thanks to @NicholasGraziano answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using postman and you are POSTing data, you need to make sure that "card_number" is your key and whatever value you want is your value. It looks like are posting "card_number" as the value for the key "card_number"

EDIT: After looking at your screenshot, you need to put the params in the BODY "form-data". You are putting those params in the url currently.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!